# how to save image to files while using matplotlib

Tags: python, scikit-image

I  am using different filters from skimage package & want to save  new image into file instead of showing on screen. Can you please help. I am pretty new user of python . below is my code

```
import os
a = 'C:'
a1 = 'Users'
a2 = 'ashay.chandra'
b = 'Downloads' 
c = 'test.jpg'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import data,io
from skimage.color import rgb2hed
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# Create an artificial color close to the orginal one
cmap_hema = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['white', 'navy'])
cmap_dab = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['white',
                                             'saddlebrown'])
cmap_eosin = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', ['darkviolet',
                                               'white'])
filename = os.path.join (a + os.sep,a1,a2,b,c)
#ihc_rgb = data.immunohistochemistry()
img = io.imread(filename)
#ihc_rgb = data.immunohistochemistry()
ihc_hed = rgb2hed(img)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7, 6), sharex=True, sharey=True,
                         subplot_kw={'adjustable': 'box-forced'})
ax = axes.ravel()
plt.savefig("'C:\Users\ashay.chandra\Documents\learning_python\test_Orig.png") = ax[0].imshow(img)
plt.savefig("'C:\Users\ashay.chandra\Documents\learning_python\4PnormC1P2_AD1_TZ1_A0_V0_M0_L0_IX_H1_Hematoxylin.png") = ax[1].imshow(ihc_hed[:, :, 0], cmap=cmap_hema)
plt.savefig("'C:\Users\ashay.chandra\Documents\learning_python\test_Eosin.png") = ax[2].imshow(ihc_hed[:, :, 1], cmap=cmap_eosin)
plt.savefig("'C:\Users\ashay.chandra\Documents\learning_python\test_DAB.png") = ax[3].imshow(ihc_hed[:, :, 2], cmap=cmap_dab)
#ax[0].imshow(img)
#ax[0].set_title("Original image")

#ax[1].imshow(ihc_hed[:, :, 0], cmap=cmap_hema)
#ax[1].set_title("Hematoxylin")

#ax[2].imshow(ihc_hed[:, :, 1], cmap=cmap_eosin)
#ax[2].set_title("Eosin")

#ax[3].imshow(ihc_hed[:, :, 2], cmap=cmap_dab)
#ax[3].set_title("DAB")

for a in ax.ravel():
    a.axis('off')

fig.tight_layout()
```

Can some one please help

Ashay

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Do you receive a particular error message? The lines ``plt.savefig(...)=...`` don't seem really  kosher. I would use ``ax[idx].figure.savefig(path)``.

Comment: I tried doing your suggested way  ax[0].figure.savefig("'C:\Users\ashay.chandra\Documents\learning_python\test_Orig.png") & I get  SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape  All I want to do is use different filters on original image & save those files.

Comment: It seems like you are having an escape character somewhere in your code and the python interpreter cannot handle it.

Comment: @AshayChandra Have a look at t[THIS BLOG](http://www.jesshamrick.com/2012/09/03/saving-figures-from-pyplot/)